# a matrix condition that involves when a set of polynomials can have GCD as $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be the ring of polynomials over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Let
>   $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n$ be elements of $R$. Prove that the greatest common
>   divisor of $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n$ is $1$ if and only if there is an
>   $n\times n$ matrix over $R$ of determinant $1$ whose first row is
>   $(p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n)$.

A set of polynomials can have GCD $1$ if they have no common roots among themselves in $\mathbb{F}$. But I don't understand how that relates with a matrix of determinant $1$ with first row consisting those polynomials. Any help is appreciated.